# How to get time interval of candlestick in candlestick chart in highchart

Tags: highcharts

I was trying candlestick chart using highchart ( highstock ) and find out that when I increase/decrease Navigator in candlestick chart the width of candlestick get changed. Sometime it display high, open, close and low for one hour interval whereas sometime it is displaying for month. I would like to grab these dynamically changed candlestick width ( not the pixel width but the real time interval) and display them in the chart title. Is there anyway I can get these information and update them dynamically in chart subtitle?

http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing are the effects of [plotOptions.series.dataGrouping](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping) (API Reference) where the data is grouped and values are approximated to display the data faster.  If you look at the example for `units` on the above linked page you'll find that you can determine and set what those groupings are.  The grouping isn't truly dynamic, it's predefined.